# How to get an unique ID using DeviceCheck API swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, devicecheck

hope all are doing good. I am working on a device check `API` now how can I get a unique id when hit the apple server?  When sending the device token from mobile to our server then Our server sends the query request to APN server like this:

```
{
 "device_token" : "wlkCDA2Hy/CfrMqVAShs1BAR/0sAiuRIUm5jQg0a..."
 "transaction_id" : "5b737ca6-a4c7-488e-b928-8452960c4be9",
 "timestamp" : 1487716472000 
}
```

Then received a response from **APN** server as **There is no bit value for this device token**

After that, I have sent the update message to apple server with bit values like

```
{
 "device_token" : "wlkCDA2Hy/CfrMqVAShs1BAR/0sAiuRIUm5jQg0a..."
 "transaction_id" : "5b737ca6-a4c7-488e-b928-8452960c4be9",
 "timestamp" : 1487716472000,
 "bit0" : false,
 "bit1" : false 
}
```

Then received the **successful** message as

```
{"status":200,"bit0":false,"bit1":false,"lastUpdated":"2018-10"}
```

But here how can I get a unique device id? Please someone help me I mess around this for 2 days. I have referred a lot of examples but nothing helped me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UUID string

> UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString

Comment: I tried the vendor Identifier. But I want a unique ID using device check API.

Comment: i didn't get your point, UUID will generate code thats app specific and each time when you install and uninstall the app it will generate a new ID

Comment: Do not use this answer if you want a persisting UUID.